# Is using Azure Active Directory for authentication recommended for customer facing applications?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are building a back-end in Azure for customer facing web and mobile (native) applications. The initial plan was to use Azure AD to manage users credentials and authentication. However, as I have been researching I have discovered the below three things which have strongly indicated to me that Azure AD is not meant to be used for auth in customer facing applications.

1. The recommended approach for login is to redirect over to the Azure AD sign in page. This page can be somewhat customized with company branding, but that branding doesn't even display in all circumstances. This method of logging in is fine for an internal company tool, but seems very tacky for a customer facing application; especially if that application is a native mobile app. This problem and a potential workaround are discussed at the link below, but the work around feels like a hack and seems to contradict all of the documentation that has been published on the subject.

https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/01/29/authenticating-to-azure-ad-non-interactively/

2. Azure AD auth requires all users to have a Microsoft account and I do not want to require my customers to create a Microsoft account if they do not already have one or if they want to use an email address for my application which is different from the email used by their Microsoft account.
3. There does not seem to be a good way to allow for the creation of users with email addresses from any domain. I could treat all of my customers as "Guest Users" in Active Directory, but then I will have to use Active Directories email invitation system every time I want to create a new user in Azure AD. This is not an option for me.

Have I stated these facts correctly? Am I correct in concluding that Azure AD is not a good choice for storing user credentials for customer facing applications? If yes, what is the recommended way of handling authentication for a customer facing application who's back end is hosted in Azure?

Thanks so much for any and all responses! There does not seem to be any discussions on this topic that I can find!

Comment: Azure AD is used for organization. Have you looked into Azure AD B2C?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview

Comment: I'd say you better take a look at [azure b2c](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, I suggest you  use [**Azure AD B2C**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) for customer facing applications.

**1. For user interface**

You can also  use the page UI customization feature to customize the look and feel of any policy.

**2. For different IDPs**

> An identity provider is a service that authenticates customer
>   identities and issues security tokens. In Azure AD B2C, you can
>   configure a number of identity providers in your tenant, such as a
>   Microsoft account, Facebook, or Amazon among others.

**3.For creation of users with email addresses from any domain**

Users can sign-up any email address of any domains with Azure AD B2C. These sign-up accounts which created by users will be local accounts and stored by Azure AD B2C.

Overall, Azure AD is used for Organization. If you want to secure your App to customers directly, Azure AD B2C is absolutely a better choice.There are many features in Azure AD B2C and you can refer to [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) for more detials.